# Select a button - webdriver Java

Tags: java, webdriver

How do I identify the button click button? Markup is this:

```
<button class="ProfileClick-actionButton  js-actionButton js-actionReClick" data-modal="ProfileClick-reClick" type="button">
    <div class="IconContainer js-tooltip" title="ReClick">
      <span class="Icon Icon--reClick"></span>
      <span class="u-hiddenVisually">ReClick</span>
    </div>
      <div class="IconTextContainer">
        <span class="ProfileClick-actionCount ProfileClick-actionCount--isZero">
          <span class="ProfileClick-actionCountForPresentation" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
  </button>
```

I tired this :

```
driver.findElement(By.className("js-actionClick")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an id to the `button`, and use that id to reference it.

```
<button id="myButton" class="ProfileClick-actionButton  js-actionButton js-actionReClick" data-modal="ProfileClick-reClick" type="button">
  ....
</button>
```

And in webdriver you would do

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.click(driver.findElement(By.id("myButton"))).perform();
```

you'll need to import `org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions`

Answer (score 0):

You can find button by class

```
driver.findElement(By.className("js-actionButton")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an XPath as below:-

```
//button[@class='ProfileClick-actionButton  js-actionButton js-actionReClick']
```

OR

```
//button[@type='button']
```

code something like below:-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='ProfileClick-actionButton  js-actionButton js-actionReClick']")).click();
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button']")).click();
```

Hope it will help you :)